# Importing Laravel Avored Package Controller in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I am trying to extend the package controller in my base laravel controller. Tried importing class using below code which shows error as class not found.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController as ControllersProductController;
use App\Imports\ProductsImport;
use AvoRed\Framework\AvoRedProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Avored\Framework\Catalog\Controllers\ProductController;

class ProductControllers extends Controller
{

    private $avored_product;

    public function __construct(ProductController $p) {
        $this->avored_product = $p;
    }

    public function index() {
        echo $this->avored_product;
    }
```

Tried multiple options by researching on it couldn't find the same. Request all to please guide me with same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you share with us the exact error message? From your code snippet I can't see which class couldn't be found.

And which Avored package are you referring to? I guess [avored-laravel-ecommerce](https://github.com/avored/laravel-ecommerce)?

If you want to extend the `ProductController`-from the package, you have properly  `extend` from that controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Avored\Framework\Catalog\Controllers\ProductController as AvoredProductController;

class ProductControllers extends AvoredProductController
{
    public function index() {
        // Do your thing in here
    }
}
```

You can now override the controller methods to your liking.